# When does the convergence of $f(\xi_n)$ imply the convergence of $\xi_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(X_1,d_1)$ and $(X_2,d_2)$ be two (complete)metric spaces. If $(\xi_n)$ is a sequence in $X_1$ and $f:X_1\rightarrow X_2$ such that $(f(\xi_n))$ is convergent in $X_2$, then my question is under what conditions can we show that $(\xi_n)$ is convergent in $X_1$. I guess it is obviously true if $f$ is a homeomorphism, but can we have weaker requirements on $f$ or is it too general to say anything else? If so can we extend it to nets/filters in general topological spaces?

In particular I am looking at the following problems.

Suppose that $(\xi_n)$ is sequence in $\mathbb{R}$, show that:

i. If $\frac{\sin \xi_n}{\xi_n}\rightarrow 1$ then $\xi_n\rightarrow 0$

ii. If for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, $(\exp[it\xi_n])$ converges in $\mathbb{C}$ then $(\xi_n)$ is convergent.

iii. If $(\exp[it\xi_n])$ converges in $\mathbb{C}$ for any $t$ in a set with positive Lebesgue measure then $(\xi_n)$ is convergent.

For i. It is easy to see $|\frac{\sin \xi_n}{\xi_n}-1|= 1-\frac{\sin \xi_n}{\xi_n}$, and is an even function. Then observing that for a $\epsilon>0$, $\inf_{t\geq\epsilon}\{1-\frac{\sin t}{t}\}:=\alpha_\epsilon>0$, so $|\frac{\sin \xi_n}{\xi_n}-1|<\alpha_\epsilon$ then implies that $|\xi_n|<\epsilon$. Any corrections, improvements or neater arguments to show this will be greatly appreciated.

For ii. I was given the idea to consider $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}(\exp[it(\xi_n-\xi_m])=1$. Then using DCT we can integrate both sides over $[-1,1]$ which reduces the problem to $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sin(\xi_n-\xi_m)}{\xi_n-\xi_m}= 1$, so then we need to use i. to infer $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}|\xi_n-\xi_m|=0$.  However I am not to comfortable with this and think they must be a nicer approach.  Secondly don't we require the double limit $\lim_{n,m\rightarrow\infty}|\xi_n-\xi_m|=0$ to infer that the $(\xi_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence? If so how do we know that the iterated and double limit will coincide? So my confusion is with the iterated limits vs double limits. Any help again is most welcome, or an alternative argument will also be appreciated.

For iii. have no idea how to proceed as sets that are nowhere dense such as the Smith-Volterra-Cantor set, have to be considered.

I would appreciate any help with regards to any of these problems and any references (basic or advanced) will also be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use the [Steinhaus theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus_theorem) for (iii)?

Comment: Note that the (stronger) condition "for any $(x_n)$ if $f(x_n)$ converges then so does $(x_n)$" is equivalent to "$f$ is injective and $f^{-1}$ is continuous".  You can easily see that it is injective by considering $f(x)=f(y)$ and taking two constant sequences.

Answer (score 1):

(edited later to clarify some issue raised in comments)

For 1 I think your proof is fine - also note that you can replace $\xi_n$ with $|\xi_n|$ and assume $0<\xi_n<\frac{\pi}{2}, n \ge n_0$ by size considerations and then $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is strictly decreasing on $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ hence is a homeomorphism from that to $[\frac{2}{\pi},1]$ etc

I will skip 2 and present a proof for 3 directly:

Since obviously $|e^{it\xi_n}|=1$, if $g(t)=\lim_{n} e^{it\xi_n}, t \in A$ of non zero measure, $|g(t)|=1, t \in A$, and $g$ is measurable so there is a measurable $f(t) \in (-\pi, \pi], t \in A$, s.t. $g(t)=e^{if(t)}, t \in A$ by taking the principal branch of the argument.

First assume $\xi_n$ is bounded when we just need $A$ uncountable. Let $\xi$ any limit point of $\xi_n$. Then obviously $g(t)=e^{if(t)}=e^{it\xi}, t \in A$ so there is an integer $k(t,\xi)$ with $f(t)-t\xi=2k(t,\xi)\pi$. Assume $\zeta$ is another limit point distinct from $\xi$ it then follows $f(t)-t\zeta=2k(t,\zeta)\pi$, so:

$t(\xi-\zeta) \in 2\pi \mathbb{Z}, t \in A$ uncountable or if $\xi-\zeta=a \ne 0$, $t \in \frac{2\pi \mathbb{Z}}{a}$ which is a countable set and that is a contradiction. Hence there is only one limit point and the sequence converges.

Assume now $\xi_n$ unbounded and wlog (passing to a subsequence, and using that the conjugate $e^{-it\xi_n}$ also converges, so we can replace $\xi_n$ by $-\xi_n$ etc) we can assume $\xi_n \to \infty$. Since the Lebesgue measure is regular, for any set of positive measure $m(A)>0$ there are bounded measurable subsets $A_k$ of $A$ for which $m(A_k) \to m(A)$, so we can take one such bounded $A_k, m(A_k) >0$ and rename it $A$ for our set of convergence and (also for convenience and later use of the standard Riemann-Lebesgue lemma) we also can scale $A$ to be in $[-\pi, \pi]$ since we just replace $t\xi_n$ by $\frac{t}{C}(C\xi_n)$ for some constant $C>0$ that makes all elements in $A$ less than $\pi$ in absolute value, while $C\xi_n$ still goes to infinity and we rename it as $\xi_n$.

Then let $\xi_n=m(n)+\alpha_n$ its decomposition into integer and fractional parts respectively, and we can assume wlog $m(n)$ strictly increasing to infinity and we also assume (by passing to a subsequence) that $\alpha_n \to \alpha$, so we reduce the problem to the case:

$e^{itm_n} \to e^{ih(t)}$ where $t \in A$ included in $[-\pi,\pi]$ of non zero measure and $m_n \to \infty$ integers, while $h$ is a measurable function with values in $[-2\pi,2\pi]$ since we can use $h(t)=f(t)-\alpha t$, and we have that $f(t) \in [-\pi,\pi], 0 \le \alpha \le 1, |t| \le \pi$.

Since obviously by Riemann-Lebesgue for Fourier series applied to $\chi(A)e^{ikt}$ (and by conjugation which switches the sign of the exponent, keeping the limit still zero), we have $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\chi(A)e^{it(m_n-k)}dt \to 0$ for any integer $k$, and since $\chi(A)e^{it(m_n-k)} \to \chi(A)e^{i(h(t)-kt)}$ for all $t \in [-\pi,\pi]$, we get by DCT $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\chi(A)e^{i(h(t)-kt)}dt=0$ for any integer $k$

But now this means that the Fourier series of the integrable function $\chi(A)e^{ih(t)}$ is zero, hence the function is zero a.e. But $|\chi(A)e^{ih(t)}|=\chi(A)$, so we get $\chi(A)=0$ a.e hence $m(A)=0$ contradiction and we are done!

Comment: Thank, you your answer, I do not quite understand it, so would appreciate it if you can clear these issues up.

Firstly, is $f$ just the principal Arg function? Is it measurable because of the arctan representation of it? And if it is not necessarily the Arg function how do we know it is then measurable?

2. When $k(t,\xi$ is defined I am sure that that is a typo and you meant integer and not integral?
3. As $\xi_n$ is real what do you mean by conjugate?
4. I know what a regular measure is but not sure why we can take A to be compact and why we need it to be in $[-\pi,\pi]$ & What is C?

Comment: 5. Why the target of $h$ is $[-2\pi,2\pi$]. 
6. If you are applying the the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma to $\chi(A)e^{ikt}$, should the minus be with the $m_n$ and not the $k$
7. My analysis is very rusty(coming from a lattice theory background), and I never really focused on harmonic analysis so after your application of DCT, I do not understand your last sentence.

So if you can help me fill in the blanks or give me a reference to help you fill in the gaps.

Comment: I will answer all but 7 and I will edit the answer to clarify that one- $g$ is measurable as the limit and then $f$ is indeed its principal argument so it is a complex logarithm (or arctangent of the real and imaginary parts) and that is measurable; 2 integer sure, 3 taking $-\xi_n$ is the same as conjugation for $e^{it\xi_n}$ so we can assume $\xi_n$ positive since we still have the limit (by conjugation of the exponential); the definition of (inner) regular is approximation by subcompacts and the condition for $A$ is just for convenience to apply riemann lebesgue on the usual $2\pi$ length

Comment: (cont) $C$ is just a scaling constant to make the compact set $A$ of the convenient size (absolute value at most $\pi$) and then we scale the $\xi$ the other way and they still go to infinity; 5 using the $f$ from above and the fact that $0 \le \alpha \le 1$ and the size of $t$ now in $A$ , so less than $\pi$, immediately gives that since $h=f-\alpha t$ (here we could repeat the argument in the first part to restrict to the principal argument again but we do not need so it is again for convenience) 6 true but conjugation again switches signs so $k-m_n$ becomes $m_n-k$ in the exponential

Comment: edited to include the comments above

Comment: and you were right with compact - what I needed was bounded and then we can also have the approximation sets relatively closed in $A$ but they do not need to be compact as subsets of the real line

Comment: Thank you for the further elucidation and your patience with my "slowness". I think I get it now, but just to clarify a few (trivial) things. Am I right to say we can take $C$ to be $\pi/diam(A)$. Changing to the conjugate in the limit here is valid as $z_n:=x_n+iy_n\rightarrow 0$ iff $x_n\rightarrow 0$ & $y_n\rightarrow 0$ iff $\bar{z_n}\rightarrow 0$. And finally to verify the wlog on why we can take a approximate set $A_j$ of $A$, as when  $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\chi(A_j)e^{i(h(t)-kt)}dt=0$, so by DCT $\lim_j\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\chi(A_j)e^{i(h(t)-kt)}dt=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\chi(A)e^{i(h(t)-kt)}dt=0$.

Comment: And $A$ need not be compact but just bounded as $A$ could be nowhere dense so would not have a compact subset.

Comment: Noted earlier and changed the fact about compact and you do not even need the last part as already $A_j$ as non zero measure for some $j$ so we can rename it as $A$ and get the contradiction there; the rest is correct (assuming that by diam you mean the supremum of absolute values in $A$)