# Does the convergence of $e^{ita_n}$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ imply the convergence of $a_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a real sequence.
Is it true that the convergence of $\{e^{ita_n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ implies the convergence of the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$?

Comment: It is enough to have $t$ in a set of positive lebesgue measure for the result to hold https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3384624/when-does-the-convergence-of-f-xi-n-imply-the-convergence-of-xi-n

Comment: @Conrad Thank you. I already suspected the Riemann Lebesgue Lemma to be involved in some way but for $A = \mathbb{R}$ ($A$ being the set of $t$ for which $e^{ita_n}$ converges) it may be indeed easier to construct a counterexample $t$ (assuming $a_n$ diverges) directly. It would be interesting know whether $A$ being of positive measure is also necessary.

Comment: I agree that it should be easier but I think the logic of the proof ($a_n$ bounded then it must have a unique limit point, $a_n$ unbounded reduces to $a_n$ integral by passing to enough subsequences and then some kind of riemann lebesgue) is still needed; it is a very good question to find sets $A$ where convergence for $t\in A$ of the exponential doesn't imply that of the sequence.

Comment: For example $a_n=2\pi n!$ shows that the rationals are such a set

Answer (score 2):

Here is a (simple?) proof that was also suggested by Conrad:
It is enough to show that $a_n$ is bounded, since then $a_n$ will have a convergent subsequence $a_{n_k} \to a$ and if $a_{m_k} \to b$ is any other converging subsequence, then $e^{it(a-b)} = 1$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, which is only possible if $a = b$. 
Suppose therefore that $a_n$ is unbounded, i.e. there exists a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ such that $|a_{n_k}| \to \infty$. 
Let $g(t) = \lim_{k \to \infty} e^{ita_{n_k}}$. 
Then $g$ is measurable and $|g(t)| = 1$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. 
By the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma and the dominated convergence theorem we have 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t)g(t) dt = \lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t)e^{ita_{nk}} dt = 0
$$
for any $f \in L^1$. 
Taking e.g. $f = \chi_{[0,1]}\bar{g}$ yields the contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

If the function $\varphi(t)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp(ita_n)$ is continuous, or even just continuous at $t=0$, then the $a_n$ converge, by (and this is ham-fisted) application of [Levy's continuity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%27s_continuity_theorem) applied to the sequence of "random" variables $X_n$ for which $P(X_n=a_n)=1$.   Conversely, if $\varphi$ is not continuous, the sequence of distributions of $X_n$ is not tight, which means in this case that the $a_n$ are unbounded.

Comment: "using Cesaro means to mimic the standard construction of sequences of genuinely random variables" - can you elaborate on what you mean by that? (Maybe a reference).

Comment: @AndreiKh  It was a half-baked idea; I'm editing it away.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, you could jump around any whole number of rotations on the circle ($\frac{2\pi k_n}{t}, k_n \in \mathbb Z$).

It would make big difference for the angle $\{\phi + \frac{2\pi i n} {t}\}$ but $0$ difference for position on circle $\{e^{2\pi i n}\}$

Comment: Any constructive feedback would be welcome.

Comment: What is your $t$? The question is asking for this to hold for ALL $t$.

Comment: @N.S. : for any given $t$, $a_{n+1} = a_n + \frac{2\pi k_n}{t}$ will move arbitrarily long in integer steps $k_n$ for angle, but nowhere on circle.

Comment: Your $a_n$ depends on the $t$. You need an example which is independent of $t$.

Comment: @N.S. ok, then I misunderstood the question.