# The sequence $(a_n)$ converges iff $(e^{i\lambda a_n})$ converges for all $\lambda \in \mathbb R$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm asked in an exercise to prove that if $(e^{i\lambda a_n})$ converges for all $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ then the sequence $(a_n)\in  \mathbb R^{\mathbb N} $ converges.

If $(a_n)$ is bounded, say $|a_n|\le M$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Then by taking $\lambda = \frac{\pi}{2M}$, since $x \mapsto e^{i\lambda x}$ is a homeomorphism of $[-M, M]$ on the half-circle $\{e^{it} \ : \ -\pi/2 \le t \le \pi/2\}$, we get that $(a_n)$ converges.

What happens if $(a_n)$ is not bounded though ?

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3433235/42969, in particular this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3434299/42969 shows that $(a_n)$ is bounded.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you ! It answers my question.